# Github Organization Folder Plugin cannot find Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I've been having issues with getting a Jenkinsfile to work with the Github Organization Folder Plugin. When scanning the repositories it says it cannot locate the Jenkinsfile when checking pull requests. When it checks the remote branch it can find the the Jenkinsfile.

Here is the output:

```
 Getting remote pull requests...

    Checking pull request #57
    (not from a trusted source)
    Job name: PR-57
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ not found
    Does not meet criteria

    Checking pull request #55
    (not from a trusted source)
    Job name: PR-55
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ not found
    Does not meet criteria

  2 pull requests were processed

  Getting remote branches...

    Checking branch add_jenkinsfile
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria

  0 branches were processed (query completed)
```

What I have trouble understanding is the difference between the remote pull requests and remote branches. Also how can it find it in the branch but not the pull request?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
Here is the result of the scan:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUcDy.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it's finding the pull requests, but refusing to touch them. This is a security thing outlined here: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/227246367-Why-Jenkinsfile-changes-Are-Not-Reflected-in-PR-Build

```
This is due to the fact the author of the Pull Request is not trusted. In that case Jenkins falls back to the Jenkinsfile of the base branch.

Changing the Jenkinsfile is equivalent to changing the job configuration. Only users with a certain level of trust should be allowed to do it.

Jenkins handles it that way: when changes to the Jenkinsfile are committed to a PR , Jenkins asks GitHub whether the PR author has the permission to push to the origin repository, if yes he is trusted, otherwise he is not.
```

Note that this can also happen if Jenkins does not have permissions to see other people's read/write access to a repository!

The "Remote" in remote pull requests and remote branches just means "searching through the pull requests and branches located on your SCM, not looking at any local git history". The difference in Jenkins is that the remote branches' Jenkinsfiles will always be trusted, but a PR's is not trusted unless the above requirements are met.

Comment: That's very interesting, I'll take a look into that. Thanks!

Comment: So I believe the reason I'm having an issues is that I am not approved to do the push. Even though my account does have read and write access, the pull request must be approved before I can actually write. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: If you get an empty Jenkinsfile merged, you can start work by re-opening your PR, and then clicking "Replay" on the Jenkins build that will be triggered. It should show an empty input box, and you can put your in progress Jenkinsfile in there. It'll look something like this: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/resources/pipeline/replay-modified.png

Once you've verified your Jenkinsfile works, and merge it in, future PRs from people w/o write access will "fall back" to the Jenkinsfile in your target branch. The reason it's not currently working is your target branch has no Jenkinsfile

Comment: Well that seemed to make it recognize the Jenkinsfile, but now it gives a `ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'` error. Oh well, progress!

Comment: As of 2017-07-19, this feature is broken in various ways and has several Jenkins tickets. You might get this error even if you seemingly did everything right.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40652
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37931

Answer (score 0):

I assume the two pull requests don't have a Jenkinsfile themselves yet.

You have one branch where you added a Jenkinsfile, so that one is detected just fine. The name looks like that is your first branch with a Jenkinsfile, that is why I assume your other pull requests don't have a Jenkinsfile yet.

A Jenkinsfile is per-branch. There is no "main"/"master" Jenkinsfile that is valid for every branch. As soon as your master branch has a Jenkinsfile, further branches will have it too and everything will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The thing is the pull request #55 is the add_jenkinsfile branch that I'm trying to merge into master. The pull request #57 also contains the same Jenkinsfile as I copied it over thinking something might be wrong with the branch. Another note, I realized the scan results does not mention the other branch that has the Jenkinsfile as the results show 2 branches. I'll update my question with a screen shot.